# Symfony autowiring interface to a real service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I need to configure an autowiring for a Symfony 2.8 application.

A service has a dependency on a `Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface`:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
class MyService
{
    /** @var EngineInterface */
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }
}
```

But I obviously get an error since this interface is implemented in three different classes.

> Unable to autowire argument of type
>   "Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface" for the service
>   "myservice". Multiple
>   services exist for th     is interface (templating.engine.delegating,
>   templating.engine.php, templating.engine.twig).

I would like to inject the `templating.engine.delegating` every time when the `EngineInterface` is required so I add a definition to my `service.yml`

```yaml
services:
  template:
    autowiring_type: 'Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface'
    alias: 'templating.engine.delegating'
```

But I still get the same error - application can not find which service to use for the `EngineInterface`

So the question is it possible to wire an interface to an already defined kernel service?

I've managed to handle similar problem when have to wire an abstract class to a service.

A service:

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;
class MyOtherService
{
    /** @var CacheProvider */
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheProvider $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

```yaml
services:
  memcache_cache:
    class: 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache'
    autowiring_types: 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider'
    calls:
    - [ setMemcache, ["@memcache"] ]
    - [ setNamespace, ["%memcache.prefix%"] ]
```

So, I've created a service (`memcache_cache`) and defined a autowiring_types for it. Every time the abstract CacheProvider is injected the `memcache_cache` should be used.

But it was easy as this is not a kernel service. I've defined it myself in a `services.yml`, whereas I don't have an access to extends the `templating.engine.delegating` service in a way to add the `autowiring_types: 'Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface'`

Comment: Have you tried to add `autowiring_types` option to definition of `templating.engine.delegating` instead of making alias? By the way, you have a typo in `autowiring_type: 'Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface'` - missing `s` in `autowiring_types`.

Comment: You were right. I've just create a new service, set `parent: templating.engine.delegating` and add `autowiring_types: Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface`.

Comment: autowiring_type has been removed so even if you get it to work it won't for long.  Check the docs dealing with multiple instances of the same interface.